# PDO Mysql, want to UPDATE even INSERT the data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, crud

I have a some problem here, where I want to update the data in CRUD, the data even adding new(like insert).

Have any idea to solve it? Thanks.

There is my code,

```
    if ($valid) {
      $pdo = Database::connect();
      $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      $sql = "UPDATE customers
              SET name = ?, email = ?, address = ?
              WHERE id = ?";
      $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
      $q->execute(array($name,$email,$address));
      Database::disconnect();
      header("Location: index.php");
    }
  }else {
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id = ?";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($id));
    $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $name = $data['name'];
    $email = $data['email'];
    $address = $data['address'];
    Database::disconnect();
  }
```

Comment: where do you bind the 4th parameter? You have 4 question marks in the query, and only 3 elements in your array while executing

Comment: have you done " new PDO(" statement yet? or are you sure of Database::connect(); because I've never seen this syntax before

Comment: Its 'id' should be in elements too?

Comment: yeah, i have done it, but in the different file

Comment: Every `?` requires a corresponding bind. It's 1:1 that way. Four `?` mean four parameters in the array.

Comment: could you please tell me what the second accolade is for ? after the header instruction,

Comment: There's `MERGE` statement for when you want to "insert or update" records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

binding id as well in the prepared statement

```
    if ($valid) {
      $pdo = Database::connect();
      $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      $values = array($name,$email,$address);
      if($id) {
          $sql = "UPDATE customers
                  SET name = ?, email = ?, address = ?
                  WHERE id = ?";
          $values[] = $id;
       } else {
          $sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name, email, address)
                  VALUES (?,?,?)";
       }
       $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
       $q->execute($values);
      Database::disconnect();
      header("Location: index.php");
    }
  }else {
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id = ?";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($id));
    $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $name = $data['name'];
    $email = $data['email'];
    $address = $data['address'];
    Database::disconnect();
  }
```

See line 8 (leave out the **)

**edit** 
added a insert query for the case $id is empty
based on understanding of a comment

Comment: Sometimes it's best to just include the line in question if everything else is unchanged.

Comment: any error messages? Wrong query executed? You should give more feedback than "not working" the have to issue solved.

Comment: it's work, but what i mean, the 'update' not be updated, even adding new data(like insert in CRUD)

Comment: I have trouble understanding that sentence. Did you mean the update-query is working now, but you also need to insert data as a new record?

Comment: I've changed the data and submit it, but in index.php the new data isn't replace the old data

Comment: replace your header() lines by ` exit('stop on line '. __LINE__);` and above echo the variabels $name, $address, $id and $email

Comment: "above echo the variabels $name, $address, $id and $email", it is in $q->execute(?)

Comment: yes: you say your query is not leading to changes in the database: either the query is wrong by itself, or the values bind to the query are not what you think.So `var_dump($id); var_dump($name); ` etc

Answer (score 0):

number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

```
$sql = "UPDATE customers
      SET name = ?, email = ?, address = ?
      WHERE id = ?";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($name,$email,$address));
```

You have four tokens ? there should be four parameters, as of :

```
$q->execute(array($name,$email,$address,$id));
```

and pay attention not put `header("Location: index.php");` in the same file as index.php, because that will cycle and you will get an error like:

> your webhost redirected you too many times